# How can I find the volume of this 4-dimensional ball?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

- Let $B$ be the $4$-dimensional ball
  $$
  \left\{(x, y, z, w): x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 \leq R^2 \right\}
  $$

in $\mathbb{R}^4$. I want to make the change of variables
$$
x=r \cos \phi, \quad y=r \sin \phi, \quad z=\rho \cos \theta, \quad w=\rho \sin \theta
$$
to compute the volume of $B$, can you help? Thanks...

$\bf{Added:}$ The substitution above means that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, $z^2 + w^2 = \rho^2$, so $r^2 +\rho^2 = R^2$.  Therefore $r = R \cos u$, $\rho = R \sin u$, where $u \in [0, \pi/2]$, since $r$, $\rho\ge 0$. Also $\phi$, $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$.

Comment: This is a *very* well-known result, and doesn't merit posing to this community.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I didn't know it, what is called this result?

Comment: @JamesEnsor It's called "the formula for the volume of a 4 dimensional ball".

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the thing that is not well known is that the calculation can be done easily, undergraduate level, by induction from dimension $n$ to dimension $n+2,$ using just a double integral in polar coordinates.

Comment: @WillJagy:  I too teach this integration method, and it is one of the problems in my textbook ***Pattern classification*** (2nd ed.).  The wikipedia page should (I think) be sufficient for an undergraduate, but your answer below is fine too.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Oh  well, if you look at comments below my answer, the "easy" method is lost on this OP. I suppose I am always hoping an OP can take my hint and run with it. Here, as you know, induction gives a pleasant formula, in even dimension no explicit gamma function needed

Comment: @WillJagy Could you say that what is the OP mean??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taught this: the main thing is to do induction by two dimensions, using polar coordinates. So: we know the volume of the $n$ ball of radius $R$ is $c_n R^n.$ Next, the unit ball in dimension $n+2.$

So, on the unit disc in dimension 2, at a point $(r, \theta)$ we integrate the $n$ volume of a ball with radius $\sqrt {1-r^2},$ which becomes $c_n (1-r^2)^{n/2}$

Our new number, called $c_{n+2},$ becomes
$$ c_{n+2} =  \int_0^{2 \pi}  \int_0^1 c_n (1-r^2)^{n/2}  r dr d\theta = 2 \pi c_n  \int_0^1  (1-r^2)^{n/2}  r dr$$

An antiderivative is
$$ \frac{-1}{n+2} \left( 1 - r^2 \right)^{\frac{n+2}{2}} \; , \; \; $$
and this is to be evaluated between $0$ and $1.$ This vanishes at endpoint $1,$ what remains is the negation of $\frac{-1}{n+2}.$ Put back the coefficients, we reach the simple
$$  c_{n+2} = \frac{2 \pi c_n}{n+2}  $$
For example, $c_1 = 2$ for the line segment of "radius" 1, or length 2. Then
$$ c_3 =  \frac{2 \pi 2}{3} = \frac{4 \pi }{3}, $$
and the volume of the ball with radius $R$ is $ \frac{4 \pi R^3}{3}$

Well, $c_2 = \pi$ for the area of the unit disc, $\pi R^2 \; . \;$ So
$$ c_4 =  \frac{2 \pi \pi}{4} = \frac{ \pi^2 }{2}, $$
and the 4-ball of radius $R$ has 4-volume $\frac{\pi^2 R^4}{2}$

Comment: Thanks for answer. Did you make change of variable in your proof?

Comment: @JamesEnsor If you use the variable name $\theta$ instead of $\phi$ in this answer it is exactly your change of variables from $x,y$ to $r,\phi.$ Since $n=2$ in your case, inside the double integral you have the area of the disk of radius $(1-r^2)$ over $z,w,$ and now you can make the second trig substitution to integrate that area.